# How can I efficiently simulate recurring events in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to do monte carlo simulating equipment failures. This seems simple enough. I want to know when equipment will fail in a given 20 year (240 month) span. So:

```
    n <- 240
    failures <- function(life, shape) {
        life <- life  + 1
        last <- runif(1,0,life)
        events  <- vector()
        while (last < n) {
            events <- c(events, last)
            last <- last + rweibull(1,shape,life)
        }
        x <- vector(length=n)
        x[events] <- 1
        x
}
```

This drops a one on every month there is a failure and resets the weibull. Can I simulate thousands of these things without all the while loops and unnecessary vectors?

It is much more efficient, for example, to just do `x[cumsum(rweibull(n,shape,life))] <- 1` but of course I cannot know the correct `n`.